# Is it possible to have multiple version of php working on the same lamp?

Tags: php, lamp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I run PHP 5.3 and PHP 5.2 on the same server with Apache?](https://serverfault.com/questions/115201/can-i-run-php-5-3-and-php-5-2-on-the-same-server-with-apache)

Is it possible to have multiple version of php working on the same lamp?Maybe using different ports?i'm thinking of having php. 5.2 when i call port 81 and php 5.3 an port 82.

Sorry if the question is stupid but i'm a newbie!

Edit - Sorry it's a dupe.Close it (i had checked before, anyway)

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know to do this would be to have two different apache instances running, each loading a different php module.